# Feathers JS. How to write custom CLI method to seed Mongoose models

Tags: mongoose, feathersjs

I would like to write a custom method for @feathers/cli to seed the database with some initial data. Can somebody please point me the direction to conveniently extend @feathers/cli?
Basically, the method should connect to feathers app and try to add records to models with `service.create({data})` calls.

Or is there any better way to seed and validate data to Feathers models? I use Feathers-mongoose adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily create your own seed scripts by requiring your `app.js`. E.g. in `seed.js`:

```
const app = require('../src/app');

(async () => {
  app.setup();
  // If you are using Sequelize:
  // await app.get('sequelizeSync');
  
  const user = await app.service('users').create({
    email: 'test@user.com',
    password: 'supersecret'
  });
  // Do other things here
})();
```

Then you can run it with `node seed`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sequelize-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-cli). Though I read somewhere they don't recommend mixing CLI's. Remember you are also using [feathers' cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@feathersjs/cli)

Install sequelize-cli. Then `npx sequelize-cli init` to create directory structure the cli can work with. Delete all the new files apart from seeders folder in the root of your app, they are not needed.
Create the migration and data by `npx sequelize-cli seed:generate --name sample-table` and edit as shown [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html#creating-the-first-seed).

The you can run the seed like so `npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all` and remove it like so `npx sequelize-cli db:seed:undo`

As long you don't get mixed up with the two cli's, this can really help save time. Remember that creating data this way wont go through the feathers hooks.

You can also add this entry into the `scripts` section of the projects `package.json`

```
"seed": "npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all",
"unseed": "npx sequelize-cli db:seed:undo:all",
```